# Transfer only a Part of Canvas to a New Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a `canvas` with an `id` of `cnv`.

```
<canvas id='cnv'></canvas>
```

[image]

The dark rectangle is the whole canvas. I want to create another canvas that contains only the white region in the old canvas. How will I transfer a part of a canvas to a new canvas?

```
 var cnv = document.getElementById('cnv');
```

I don't know what to do next in my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the region specificed in x, y, width and height, you can do:

```
function regionToCanvas(canvas, x, y, w, h) {

    var c = document.createElement("canvas"),       // create new canvas
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");                   // context for new canvas

    c.width = w;                                    // set size = w/h
    c.height = h;

    ctx.drawImage(canvas, x, y, w, h,  0, 0, w, h); // draw in region at (0,0)
    return c;                                       // return canvas
}
```

Then call, example:

```
var newCanvas = regionToCanvas(cnv, x, y, width, height);
document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);              // add to DOM
```